# API for running modeler flow?

Tags: watson-studio

my customer wants to run modeler flow with date and time specified.
I know a schedule function of modeler flow is not provided with Watson Studio.

So, I'm looking for API to run modeler flow. 
Do you have any APIs to run modeler flow like following URL? 
https://medium.com/ibm-watson/using-shell-scripts-to-control-data-flows-created-in-watson-applications-f7de2e265f1f

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not yet a public API available for modeler flows in Watson Studio. This is something we will support in the future, but [please submit your idea here](http://ibm.biz/dsxideas) to let us know what you would like to see and let others vote on your idea.